# PHP - Access other class type variable

Tags: php

I am new to PHP OO and I have a question about define a class.
For example, I have 2 class:

```
class A
{
    // public $b = new B;   <-- I want something like this
    // But the instruction above is error. I have search and found another way without error

    public $b;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $b = new B;
    }
}

class B
{
    public $value = 1;
}

$a = new A;
// echo $a->b->value; <--Error!
```

How can I access to `$a->b->value`? What if there is a variable from class C in class B (`$a->b->c->value`)?

Thank you.